# how to permit parameters for profile creation along with devise user signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, associations, strong-parameters

I have the classic has_one/belongs_to association between user and profile models, and user accepts_nested_attributes for profile. In the signup form, one of the inputs establishes the username attribute of the profile model. This attribute is correctly saved, but the rails server spits out "Unpermitted parameter: profile_attributes". Even though there doesn't seem to be any actual errors in the result, I'd like to know why I'm getting this message and eliminate it.

My registrations_controller.rb

```
  def new
    build_resource({})
    resource.build_profile
    set_minimum_password_length
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with self.resource
  end

  def sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:sign_up)
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, profile_attributes: [:username])
  end
```

They relevant part of my form code (if it matters at all) is:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :profile do |p| %>
    <%= p.input :username, required: true %>
  <% end %>
  ...
```

I tried adding `profile_attributes: [:username]` to params.require in users_controller.rb and that didn't eliminate the error message either.

Comment: My bad, I used mobile, and couldn't see. The unpermitted parameter is harmless as long as everything is working fine.

Comment: really? could you give me a better idea of why it's saying this at all? is it a rails bug?

Comment: Does every profile have a unique username attribute?  I can show you how to avoid this error just let me know what unique value you are using from the profile model to add to the user since it isn't the standard (like profile_id)

Comment: I actually don't have any unique indexes or validations on the username attribute yet, but I will. Currently the relationship is a pretty standard user has_one profile / profile belongs_to user. The profile model has a user_id column that I added with an AddUserToProfiles migration using the standard add_reference line.